# Error when parsing JavaScript using Python and JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to find the specific URL of a .ics file when given the URL of a general webpage containing that .ics calendar (ex. http://miamioh.edu/emss/offices/career-services/events/index.html). I originally tried using beautiful soup to parse/search, which was successful for other sites, but not for this site which has JavaScript. I then tried using JSON to see if a URL containing '.ics' was in one of the lines, but that didn't work either (nothing was printed). Why do none of the lines contain '.ics' when I try searching for it?

EDIT: As a comment noted below, the html code does not contain '.ics', so I am trying to figure out how to get the link containing '.ics' that is present in the image embedded [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKWr9.png)

```
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:


    if link.get('href') != None and '.ics' in link.get('href'):
        endout = link.get('href')

        if endout[:6] == 'webcal':
            endout = 'https' + endout[6:]
        print
        print 'URL: ' + endout
        print
        return endout
    break



# code for searching JavaScript using JSON

for line in urllib2.urlopen(url):

    if '.ics' in line:
        print line
```

Comment: The raw html source of that url does not, in fact, contain any .ics links.  There must be some javascript shenanigans going on to alter the page content after it loads into a browser.

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen()` and `requests.get()`, as used here, will essentially yield the same information (though in different objects, and with some different methods). Compare the output of `page` and `urlopen(url)` -- in both cases it's just the DOM. You should look into Selenium: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @JohnGordon Would this require parsing javascript even though the .ics URL is within a <a href> tag? I am really confused about how to go about locating this.

Comment: Not only would you have to parse the javascript, you'd then have to _run_ the javascript to get its effect.  As @cmaher commented, Selenium is really the tool for this job.